# Tkinter example code for multiple windows, why won't buttons load correctly?

Tags: python, class, tkinter, destroy

I am writing a program which should:

1. Open a window with the press of a button.
2. Close the newly opened window with the press of another button.

I'm using classes so I can insert the code into a larger program later. However, I can't get my buttons to load correctly.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Demo1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self)
        self.pack()
        self.master.title("Demo 1")
        self.button1 = tk.Button(self, text = "Button 1", width = 25,
                               command = self.new_window)
        self.button1.grid(row = 0, column = 1, columnspan = 2, sticky = tk.W+tk.E+tk.N+tk.S)

    def new_window(self):
        self.newWindow = Demo2()

class Demo2(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        new = tk.Frame.__init__(self)
        new = tk.Toplevel(self)
        new.title("Demo 2")
        new.button = tk.Button(text = "Button 2", width = 25,
                               command = self.close_window)
        new.button.pack()

    def close_window(self):
        self.destroy()

def main():
    Demo1().mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I rewrote your code in a more organized, better-practiced way:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Demo1:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.button1 = tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'New Window', width = 25, command = self.new_window)
        self.button1.pack()
        self.frame.pack()

    def new_window(self):
        self.newWindow = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        self.app = Demo2(self.newWindow)

class Demo2:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.quitButton = tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'Quit', width = 25, command = self.close_windows)
        self.quitButton.pack()
        self.frame.pack()

    def close_windows(self):
        self.master.destroy()

def main(): 
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Demo1(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Result:

[image: Demo1 window]  [image: Demo2 window]

Comment: @ADB It depends. Generally, running two `mainloop()`s on two `Tk()` windows is looked down upon. However, if you want multiple windows, it's possible to avoid two `mainloop()`s. Thus, you can use the `Toplevel()` widget which is similar to `Tk()`.

Comment: Two mainloops doesn't "depend" on anything and it isn't just "looked down upon", it's flat out wrong. You only need one. A call to mainloop is an infinite loop, when you run more than one you have an infinite loop inside an infinite loop.  You should remove the second call to `mainloop` in your code (in Demo1.new_window), otherwise it will be confusing to people who are trying to learn how to use Tkinter.

Comment: Could you explain `close_windows()`? When does it have to be called?

Comment: @sbhatla `close_window()` is called when the "Quit" button of class `Demo2` is clicked. Using the parameter `command` in `tk.Button()` creates this link.

Comment: Is there a reason you decided against `class Demo1()` inheriting `tk.Frame`?

Answer (score 13):

You need to specify the master for the second button. Otherwise it will get packed onto the first window. This is needed not only for `Button`, but also for other widgets and non-gui objects such as `StringVar`.

**Quick fix:** add the frame `new` as the first argument to your `Button` in `Demo2`.

**Possibly better:** Currently you have `Demo2` inheriting from `tk.Frame` but I think this makes more sense if you change `Demo2` to be something like this,

```
class Demo2(tk.Toplevel):     
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self)
        self.title("Demo 2")
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Button 2", # specified self as master
                                width=25, command=self.close_window)
        self.button.pack()

    def close_window(self):
        self.destroy()
```

Just as a suggestion, you should only import `tkinter` once. Pick one of your first two import statements.

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import Tkinter as tk

from Tkinter import *

class windowclass():

        def __init__(self,master):
                self.master = master
                self.frame = tk.Frame(master)
                self.lbl = Label(master , text = "Label")
                self.lbl.pack()
                self.btn = Button(master , text = "Button" , command = self.command )
                self.btn.pack()
                self.frame.pack()

        def command(self):
                print 'Button is pressed!'

                self.newWindow = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
                self.app = windowclass1(self.newWindow)

class windowclass1():

        def __init__(self , master):
                self.master = master
                self.frame = tk.Frame(master)
                master.title("a")
                self.quitButton = tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'Quit', width = 25 , command = self.close_window)
                self.quitButton.pack()
                self.frame.pack()


        def close_window(self):
                self.master.destroy()


root = Tk()

root.title("window")

root.geometry("350x50")

cls = windowclass(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried to use more than two windows using the Rushy Panchal example above. The intent was to have the change to call more windows with different widgets in them. The butnew function creates different buttons to open different windows. You pass as argument the name of the class containing the window (the second argument is nt necessary, I put it there just to test a possible use. It could be interesting to inherit from another window the widgets in common.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Demo1:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry("400x400")
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.butnew("Window 1", "ONE", Demo2)
        self.butnew("Window 2", "TWO", Demo3)
        self.frame.pack()

    def butnew(self, text, number, _class):
        tk.Button(self.frame, text = text, width = 25, command = lambda: self.new_window(number, _class)).pack()

    def new_window(self, number, _class):
        self.newWindow = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        _class(self.newWindow, number)


class Demo2:
    def __init__(self, master, number):
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry("400x400+400+400")
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.quitButton = tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'Quit', width = 25, command = self.close_windows)
        self.label = tk.Label(master, text=f"this is window number {number}")
        self.label.pack()
        self.quitButton.pack()
        self.frame.pack()

    def close_windows(self):
        self.master.destroy()

class Demo3:
    def __init__(self, master, number):
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry("400x400+400+400")
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.quitButton = tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'Quit', width = 25, command = self.close_windows)
        self.label = tk.Label(master, text=f"this is window number {number}")
        self.label.pack()
        self.label2 = tk.Label(master, text="THIS IS HERE TO DIFFERENTIATE THIS WINDOW")
        self.label2.pack()
        self.quitButton.pack()
        self.frame.pack()

    def close_windows(self):
        self.master.destroy()




def main(): 
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Demo1(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

#### Open the new window only once

To avoid having the chance to press multiple times the button having multiple windows... that are the same window, I made this script (take a look at [this page](https://pythonprogramming.altervista.org/tkinter-open-a-new-window-and-just-one/) too)

```
import tkinter as tk


def new_window1():
    global win1
    try:
        if win1.state() == "normal": win1.focus()
    except:
        win1 = tk.Toplevel()
        win1.geometry("300x300+500+200")
        win1["bg"] = "navy"
        lb = tk.Label(win1, text="Hello")
        lb.pack()


win = tk.Tk()
win.geometry("200x200+200+100")
button = tk.Button(win, text="Open new Window")
button['command'] = new_window1
button.pack()
win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -2):

What you could do is copy the code from `tkinter.py` into a file called `mytkinter.py`, then do this code:

```
import tkinter, mytkinter
root = tkinter.Tk()
window = mytkinter.Tk()
button = mytkinter.Button(window, text="Search", width = 7,
                               command=cmd)
button2 = tkinter.Button(root, text="Search", width = 7,
                               command=cmdtwo)
```

And you have two windows which don't collide!

Comment: What a terrible idea. What about creating multiple windows dynamically? With your approach, you would then need to dynamically copy ```tkinter.py``` and add its copy to python path, then obtain proper classes from imported file, not to mention that in some cases you need to keep a reference to your UI elements somewhere so that GC won't get rid of them... no, just no.