# Tkinter canvas problem, started coding 3 days ago

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

[Look at this](https://gyazo.com/fdcc4d8a98d8c5c8e2a4c04f92a108b3) I need to know how to switch between windows easily bceause the method I used did not work at all, i tried destroying the previous canvas and adding a new one between every switch. It worked fine with 2 canvases but when 3 came to play the code just didnt work.

---

this is the whole code btw.

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(window, width=400, height=300, bg='gray35', relief='groove', bd=8)
canvas1.pack()

label1 = tk.Label(text='The Guess Game!', font=('Comic Sans MS', 25,'bold'), bg='white', fg='black', bd=8, relief='raised')
canvas1.create_window(200,85, window=label1)

def startGame():
    canvas1.destroy()
    global canvas2
    canvas2 = tk.Canvas(window, width=400, height=300, bg='gray45', relief='groove', bd=8)
    canvas2.pack(side='left')

    btn2 = tk.Button(relief='ridge', bg='green2', width=10, height=5, command=gameEasy)
    canvas2.create_window(100, 150, window=btn2)

    btn3 = tk.Button(relief='ridge', bg='yellow2', width=10, height=5)
    canvas2.create_window(200, 150, window=btn3)

    btn4 = tk.Button(relief='ridge', bg='red2', width=10, height=5)
    canvas2.create_window(300, 150, window=btn4)

    backbtn = tk.Button(width='3', relief='groove', text='x',font=('Calibri', 10,'bold'), bd='8', bg='red', command=goBack)
    canvas2.create_window(30, 30, window=backbtn)

    lbleasy = tk.Label(text='Easy', bg='gray20', fg='white', font=('Impact', 18, 'bold'), bd='8', relief='sunken')
    canvas2.create_window(100, 75, window=lbleasy)

    lblmed = tk.Label(text='Medium', bg='gray20', fg='white', font=('Impact', 18, 'bold'), bd='8', relief='sunken')
    canvas2.create_window(200, 75, window=lblmed)

    lblhard = tk.Label(text='Hard', bg='gray20', fg='white', font=('Impact', 18, 'bold'), bd='8', relief='sunken')
    canvas2.create_window(300, 75, window=lblhard)

    infeasy = tk.Label(text='You have \nan unlimited\namount of\nguesses and the\nsecret number is\nbetween 1-20.', bg='gray45', fg='white', font=('Arial', 10, 'normal'), relief='flat')
    canvas2.create_window(100, 250, window=infeasy)

    infmed = tk.Label(text='You have 25\nguesses and\nthe secret\nnumber is\nbetween 1-50.', bg='gray45', fg='white', font=('Arial', 10, 'normal'), relief='flat')
    canvas2.create_window(200, 250, window=infmed)

    infhard = tk.Label(text='You have 15\n guesses and\nthe secret\n numberis between\n1-100.', bg='gray45', fg='white', font=('Arial', 10, 'normal'), relief='flat')
    canvas2.create_window(300, 250, window=infhard)

def goBack():
    canvas2.destroy()
    global canvas1
    canvas1 = tk.Canvas(window, width=400, height=300, bg='gray35', relief='groove', bd=8)
    canvas1.pack()

    label1 = tk.Label(text='The Guess Game!', font=('Comic Sans MS', 25,'bold'), bg='white', fg='black', bd=8, relief='raised')
    canvas1.create_window(200,85, window=label1)
    
    btn1 = tk.Button(text='Start Game!', command=startGame, font=('Impact', 20, 'bold'), relief='ridge')
    canvas1.create_window(200,180,window=btn1)
    
def gameEasy():
    canvas2.destroy()
    global canvas3
    canvas3 = tk.Canvas(window, width=400, heigth=300, bg='gray25', relief='groove', bd=8)
    canvas3.pack


btn1 = tk.Button(text='Start Game!', command=startGame, font=('Impact', 20, 'bold'), relief='ridge')
canvas1.create_window(200,180,window=btn1)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16115616/14475852) @NgBANAN

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled "height" in this line:

```
 canvas3 = tk.Canvas(window, width=400, heigth=300, bg='gray25', relief='groove', bd=8)
```

Comment: Well that's embarrassing.. ;D