# How to open a new window which is in another class in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import PIL
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import time


class Sharingan(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.geometry("60x60+1465+750")
        self.config()

        self.photo_sharingan = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="sharingan.png")

#this button has to open a new window on button click:     
        self.btn_sharingan = Button(image=self.photo_sharingan, bd=0,
                                    command=lambda: [self.change_btn_img(),self.open_main_window()])
        self.btn_sharingan.place(x=-3, y=-4)

        self.photo_sharingan2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="sharingan-2.png")
        self.btn_sharingan2 = Button(image=self.photo_sharingan2, bd=0, command=lambda: [self.change_btn_img2()],
                                     highlightbackground="black")
        self.btn_sharingan2.place_forget()

        self.overrideredirect(True)

    def change_btn_img(self):
        self.btn_sharingan.place_forget()
        self.btn_sharingan2.place(x=-3, y=-4)

    def change_btn_img2(self):
        self.btn_sharingan2.place_forget()
        self.btn_sharingan.place(x=-3, y=-4)

#this is the function but how do I make it to initialize and mainloop class-MainWindow
def open_main_window():
    

class MainWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.geometry("200x100")



app1 = Sharingan()
app1.mainloop()
```

So basically I want to open a new window whose code is in another class from a button click. This button is in class1. How can I accomplsh this? The function is 'open_main_window' an the button is 'sharingan'. I just want to open a new window when this button is clicked what code should I write in the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open a new window you use `tk.Toplevel()` so your function would be:

```
def open_main_window(self):
   self.newWindow = tk.Toplevel()
```

For more info on `tk.Toplevel()` check out [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_toplevel.htm)

Comment: Really helpful thanks a lot

Comment: so now how do I add widgets to that new window.

Comment: Are you trying to add a widget/widgets from the ```open_main_window``` function, or in a different function?

Comment: Not a problem, if you are happy with the original answer to your main question, can you click the tick to say that you have accepted it. I will try and find some tutorial that might help.

Comment: [Good Youtube Video on This Subject](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bl5xdJ-b8GQ),
[The Answer to This Question is a Good Demo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16115378/tkinter-example-code-for-multiple-windows-why-wont-buttons-load-correctly)